# Why crud repository existBy (2 values) finds case insensitive instead of case sensitive?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa

I keep in my database domains per organisation, and I'm using method `existsByMailDomainAndOrganisationId` to check if new domain which I want to add is already exists in this organisation.

What i read in various documentations and pages I saw it should be case sensitive by default but when I have already *mail@domain.com* and want add *mail@Domain.com*, `existBy...` returns that it already exist (`findBy...` for *mail@Domain.com* and *organisationId* returns *mail@domain.com*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely caused by your database and schema setup. For example if you are using MySQL as per [10.1 Character Sets and Collations in General](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-general.html) strings are compared using  a variety of collations. Some database default to case-insensitivity string comparison collations e.g. SQL Server.

Comment: I forgot to mention it by I use MySql so it would be it, thanks